# Can PCA be used for row reduction

Tags: python-3.x, data-mining, pca

I had a doubt about Principle Component analysis. If the variables are along the row:

```
            delhi| kolkata|  up|  mp|  bihar|  assam|
popolation   1.2 |   2.2  | 1.3| 1.4|   2   |   1.1 |
      crop    a  |    b   |  c |   a|   b   |     c |
  avg temp    1  |    2   |  3 |   4|   5   |     6 |
 soil ph      1  |    2   |  1 |   3|   2   |     1 |
```

And one wants to do PCA to obtain most important uncorrelated variables, can one do that. The idea is not to reduce the columns but rows.

If anyone could explain this concept to me it would be very helpful as my understanding is variables exist only along columns and there are many code examples in python for column dimension reduction using pca. But I am not sure if row reduction is the same thing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Row reduction do exist, some call it clustering and some call it segmentation. You can start with hierarchial clustering, kmeans, dbscan etc. But it seems this is not what you want. You may just transpose your data and do PCA. If you provide a workable example with expected outcome. Then probably it will beore clear for a sufficient answer.

Comment: Thanks. The idea here is to reduce the number of rows which might be correlated. For example instead of having both avg temp and soil ph, if its found that they are correlated then drop one and use the other. Here the rows are the variables and the point is to keep only independent variables. I rather like the suggestion of having transpose and PCA, but in case you could suggest soemthing more after this comment - I really look forward to it

Comment: Feeling motivated to learn more - may I please request you to look into this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67367054/how-to-do-feature-selection-using-pca-and-python

Comment: PCA as the name suggests, is to analyse the principle/major components, which in case of ML, are the features; and components/features are represented in column, each row captures a different observation of a series of features. When we have a large number of components/features, we'll first find out what the principle ones are; to express this idea in mathematics, it is column dimension reduction; it is to remove the unimportant ones and keep only the major components. Removing observations (rows) therefore, do not help us achieve our goal.